# How do I diagnose why a VPS is freezing?

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, freeze, vps

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 VPS (1cpu, 512MB ram, swap 1024MB) with Apache, mySQL, sendmail and sshd, sometime it freeze, I can't access neither through ssh nor with VNC provided by the vps provider, the only choice i have is to reboot. There are no usefull logs to understand why the vps was stalled except sendmail reporting a load average above ten. I'm guessing the overload is from apache or mysql even if my site at the moment is serving 10-20 clients per day. Which steps should I follow to isolate the problem and get a clue of what is going on randomly on my server?

Answer (score 0):

I may recommend you to use `atop` monitoring utility. Like usual `top` amd `htop` utilities it allows you to have real-time monitoring, but it also allows you to have historical information about your system. Looking into it (CPU load, RAM usage, I/O etc.) you may receive the whole information about what process and when causes "freezing".

[Here](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/121222.aspx) is a sample brief article - how to set up historical monitoring using atop.

Comment: I've used atop for a couple of weeks, time to time mysql and apache are on top.. at random time, i guess I'll never know.